# It is good for my health to drink coffee 10 times a day?

Tags: health, caffeine, coffee-culture

I am working on a computer 15 hours a day, and I feel tired and sleepy a lot between the work. So I prefer to drink coffee to get rid of tiredness. Coffee gives me an energy boost and makes me able to focus on work. And if I don't drink coffee then I can't do the work properly and makes me very sick. It's not like an addiction but I need something that keeps me focused and coffee does that. So what should I do, I should stop drinking that much coffee or should continue drinking daily. It is safe and good for my body to drink coffee 10 times a day?

Comment: "*if I don't drink coffee then I can't do the work properly and makes me very sick. It's not like an addiction*" Maybe,  BUT  it is just like an addiction.

Answer (score 5):

Caffeine content of coffee varies widely depending on many factors. How much caffeine does your 10 cups contain? And how much is too much? The Mayo Clinic website has addressed exactly what you are concerned about in their detailed article which can be read here:

https://www.mayoclinic.org/healthy-lifestyle/nutrition-and-healthy-eating/in-depth/caffeine/art-20045678

Important extracts:

> How much is too much?
>   Up to 400 milligrams (mg) of caffeine a day appears to be safe for most healthy adults. That's roughly the amount of caffeine in four cups of brewed coffee, 10 cans of cola or two "energy shot" drinks. Keep in mind that the actual caffeine content in beverages varies widely, especially among energy drinks.
>
> [...]
>
> You may want to cut back if you're drinking more than 4 cups of caffeinated coffee a day (or the equivalent) and you're experiencing side effects such as:
>
> Migraine headache
>
> Insomnia
>
> Nervousness
>
> Irritability
>
> Restlessness
>
> Frequent urination or inability to control urination
>
> Stomach upset
>
> Fast heartbeat
>
> Muscle tremors
>
> [...]
>
> Most adults need seven to eight hours of sleep each night. But caffeine, even in the afternoon, can interfere with this much-needed sleep.
>
> Chronically losing sleep — whether it's from work, travel, stress or too much caffeine — results in sleep deprivation. Sleep loss is cumulative, and even small nightly decreases can add up and disturb your daytime alertness and performance.
>
> Using caffeine to mask sleep deprivation can create an unwelcome cycle. For example, you may drink caffeinated beverages because you have trouble staying awake during the day. But the caffeine keeps you from falling asleep at night, shortening the length of time you sleep.

That's also my personal experience as a long-time coffee 'addict', though I am also very sensitive to caffeine and therefore I can tolerate just 2 cups a day before I lose sleep and begin to experience strong physical effects. The key thing is to make sure you don't experience symptoms of caffeine excess, and that you get adequate sleep every day, which also varies from person to person.

If you feel the need to reduce your coffee intake, the same article linked above provides some useful guidelines.

Comment: I do have caffeine sensitivity too, it gives me a rapid heartbeat, a slight feeling of nausea and some other nasty side effects. I think I have "acquired" the caffeine sensitivity after drinking a loooot of coffee and energy drinks for three months because I had to work at night and sleep in the morning. So I advice the OP to ask a doctor or specialist instead!

Answer (score 1):

Um.  I'd stop drinking coffee ten times a day.  Is it a full cup each time?  Also, even if it were safe, I guarantee it's not good/positive for your health.  Have you tried focusing on your breathing, stretching, or getting fresh air to help get you through your long work day?

Comment: Welcome! Do you happen to have any sources that you could link to about your claim? What would be the recommend maximum amount per day? You can always [edit] your post to include more information. As for all new users, I suggest you take the [tour] and browse through our [help] to learn more about how the site and the Stack Exchange network works.

Comment: No, it's half the cup. I think the same that this much coffee is going to harm me. And yeah, I have tried small walk to get some fresh air to refresh but not it does not make any good impact. But I am looking forward to stopping drinking this much of coffee because slowly and slowly this is changing in addiction.

Comment: But how big is the cup? European tea cups are much smaller than the average American coffee mug. A "cup" is eight fluid ounces. For comparison, a can of soda is 1.5 cups. A pint of beer is 2 cups. A 20oz bottle of soda is 2.5 cups. You can check this yourself by filling your coffee cup(s) with water, then dumping into a liquid measuring cup. Some cups also print their capacity on the bottom.

Comment: Also, caffeine's effects on the brain, with sufficient exposure over a sufficient period, will "train" the brain to believe that the effects of caffeine are normal. Therefore, if you don't take caffeine, you feel down and slow. You have a caffeine dependency. If you reduce caffeine intake, you can (over time) reduce that dependency. But it *will* make you feel bad until your body starts to adjust to the new normal.

Answer (score 0):

I suffer the same problem, I only have 4 coffees at home but they are large mugs with 4 shots per mug per day.
I find best to have a couple of detox days each week and even on the days of heavy consumption drink plenty of plain water to keep kidneys flushed.
I acknowledge it's a vice and I have an addiction however I have not drank alcohol in many years don't have other substances or smoke so it's either coffee or motorbike riding that will most likely shorten my life (lol).

Comment: Welcome to Coffee! If you have a NEW question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](//coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. If you have sufficient reputation, [you may upvote](//coffee.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-up) the question. Alternatively, "star" it as a favorite and you will be notified of any new answers.